# Is there a way of using lookup_field to viewsets (Default router) instead of generic view (Simple Router)? (DRF)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls, django-serializer

I want to use slug as my pk by using *lookup_field*.
The error I have is *"Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "service-detail"*.

I figured that if I use generic view(ListAPIView or RetrieveAPIView), it'll work because in urls I can set up a simple route like path('services/slug/').
But I would like to know if there is a way of doing this with **Viewsets**. Which means how can I set up the urls **(Default Router instead of Simple Router)** to handle this?

**serializers.py**

```py
class ServiceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    slug = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    description = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    price = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    service_image = ServiceImageSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = ('url', 'slug', 'title', 'description', 'price', 'service_image')
        lookup_field = 'slug'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'lookup_field':'slug'}
        }

    def get_slug(self, instance):
        return slugify(instance.vendor.username + "-" + instance.title)
```

**views.py**

```py
class ServiceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Service.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ServiceSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'
```

**urls.py**

```py
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('categories', CategoryViewSet)
router.register('services', ServiceViewSet)
router.register('images', ServiceImageViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Comment: ```path('categories', CategoryViewSet.as_view(dict(get='list', post='create', put='update')), name='category_view_set')```

Why not?

Comment: Thank you for your response!

```python 
path('services/', ServiceViewSet.as_view({ 'get': 'list', 'post': 'create'}), name='service_view_set'),
path('services/<slug>/', ServiceViewSet.as_view({ 'get': 'retrieve', 'put': 'update', 'patch': 'partial_update', 'delete': 'destroy'}), name='service_view_set'), ```

I did something like what you have suggested, it works for the detail-view which is using (services/<slug>/) but **it doesn't work on retrieving a normal list-view** (services/) Sorry, I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to not use Viewsets anymore and using this instead:
**views.py**

```py
class ServiceListAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Service.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ServiceSerializer        

class ServiceDetailAPIView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Service.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ServiceSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'
```

**urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('services/', ServiceListAPIView.as_view(), name='service-list'),
    path('services/<slug>/', ServiceDetailAPIView.as_view(), name='service-detail'),
]
```